# Installing a scala "ecosystem" on Linux (debian)?

Tags: scala, debian

Newbie to scala.

Reading some descriptions of how to install a scala ecosystem has me confused. I will be installing on a apt-based linux system. My choice of editor/ide will be emacs ( though I might play with Eclipse and IntelliJ ).
Not a java programmer. I also like to do projects as different users for different purposes.

From what I understand the steps are:

1. Install sbt from the linux distro repo as root.
2. Install the newest sbt from the installed sbt as root.
3. Install the newest scala from sbt as root.
4. Install ensime from sbt as root.
  ( or do I install it from melpa? )

Also I heard of something called Scala Worksheet which might be useful. The version I heard of is a Eclipse plusin. Is there a version that can be used with emacs?

Answer (score 1):

You can install ensime as normal user from MELPA without problems. Just read carefully the instructions in their [web page](http://ensime.github.io). It is important to install the ensime SBT plugin in the user directory instead of the project plugin directory.

The ensime integration works way better that Eclipse's Scala IDE.

About the worskheet, it would be nice to have it in emacs but it is not really needed . You can work quite fine just with sbt.